# Use the same dbcontext in multiple methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, singleton, dbcontext

i have a problem, i would use same dbContext in multiple methods, example:

```
public class Communication
{
   public Response AddCommunication(Commnucation myComm)
   {
      using(MYDB dbContenxt = new MYDB())
       {
           DBCOMMUNICATION dbComm = new DBCOMMUNICATION
           {
               ID = myComm.Id,
               NAME = myComm.Name,
               SUBJECT = myComm.Subject,
               MESSAGE = myComm.Message
           };

           if(myComm.Images != null && myComm.Images.Count > 0)
           {
               foreach(var image in Images)
               {
                   IMAGES dbImages = new IMAGES
                   {
                       ID_COMMUNICATION = myComm.Id,
                       NAME = image.Name,
                       VALUE = image.Value
                   };
                   dbContext.IMAGES.add(dbImages);
               }
           }

           if(myComm.Attachments != null && myComm.Attachments.Count > 0)
           {
               foreach(var image in Images)
               {
                   same work .......
                }
           }
        dbContext.SaveChanges();    
       }
      .......
      .......
    }
}
```

i would extract methods that use foreach loop, example:

```
 if(myComm.Images != null && myComm.Images.Count > 0)
       {
            AddImages(myComm);
       }
```

and in the method AddImages i would use the same dbContext for add but use SaveChanges only in AddCommunication.
Which is the best practice to do this?? Use a Singleton Pattern for dbContext? Please help me. Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Pass dbContext as an argument to that new method (AddImages).

Comment: I read about stackoverflow that is not good practice, for performance reasons

Comment: It cannot be bad for perfomance reasons, because it does not affect perfomance in any way. You just do the same you are doing now, but extracting part of functionality to different method. You are not creating new context or something like that.

Comment: You can use Dependency Injection for this. You did not mention if it's an web application, but if it is, you can register the dbContext per request. All the methods will operate in the same context.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass dbContext to the new method

```
if(myComm.Images != null && myComm.Images.Count > 0)
{
   AddImages(dbContext, myComm);
}

...

private void AddImages(MYDB dbContext,Commnucation myComm)
{
   ...
}
```